# Remove space around string within DOM element using PHP

Tags: php

I have this piece of code that is supposed to strip the blank spaces before and after a string contained within a DOM element.

Here is the PHP part:

```
//This returns the browser url
$browserUrl = curPageURL();
//This should be removeing the spaces
$changedUrl = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $browserUrl);
echo $changedUrl;
```

And this is what is returned in the DOM:

[image]

So what's the best way to get rid of that space?

Comment: You would also want to trim away new lines (if they exist?)  Also, there are other PHP functions that can get for you the current URL that is in the browser address bar. http://webcheatsheet.com/php/get_current_page_url.php

Comment: Just take away that space before and after the url

Comment: You do not need the the preg_replace. If you can get the value itself (and it's the exact and full URL) you can use php's `trim()` function to remove space before and after (top and tail).

Comment: Where is that `<div>` coming from? A template? A `DOMElement` object? I suspect it's *not* actually coming from that `curPageURL()` function.

Comment: Good question. I think it's the way I wrote the div.. just sec. That was it, thanks!

Comment: An alternate way of removing the spaces would be to give that div an id first, and then use jQuery to run the trim (jQuery's version of trim) function on the textual value of that div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$changedUrl = preg_replace( '/^\R$/', '', $browserUrl);
```